# Typescript: union of interface properties names when interface inherits

Tags: typescript

We have that code:

```
export interface SingleAction {
//...
}

export interface Actions {
    [key: string]: SingleAction
}

//

export interface ExampleActions extends Actions {
    testAction: {
        //...
    }

    testAction2: {
        //...
    }
}
```

Abstract type `Actions` is just for guarding shapes of real ActionList like types (for example `ExampleActions`)

Now we need type that is union of all properties names in ExampleActions:

```
// expecting Test to be "testAction" | "testAction2" but instead it's string
type Test = keyof ExampleActions; 

const a: Test = "gfhgfh"; // valid, but should require only "testAction" | "testAction2"
```

When I drop `extends Actions` in line `export interface ExampleActions extends Actions {` then it works as expected.

How to make it happen without droping it?

Why I need it?

I want to some class knows allowed parameteres in some method call, like this:

```
class ActionsManager<CALLABLE_ACTIONS extends Actions> {
    callAction(name: keyof CALLABLE_ACTIONS) {
        //...
    }
}

const am = new ActionsManager<ExampleActions>();

am.callAction("testAction"); //good
am.callAction("testAction2"); //good
am.callAction("anotherAction"); //wrong, there is no property "anotherAction" in "ExampleActions" interface
```

May be related:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24274

https://github.com/DanielXMoore/Civet/issues/271

looks like it isn't possible right now? But there is keyword `satisfies` that some people consider to introduce to Typescript syntax.

Comment: So you don't actually want `ExampleActions` to extend `Actions`?  Or you do but then you want to extract out the non-string-index keys from `ExampleActions`?  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbEV4N) shows what to do in each case.  Do either of those satisfy your needs? If so tell me which and I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Incredible, You are Typescript Wizard  Thank You, it works perfectly, now I need to study it how it works. Answering Your question: it was `IfNeeded` from playground that I have needed

Comment: I'll write up an answer explaining when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz Could u look at this too? Both `T1` and `T2` ends up as numbers, but `T2` shouldn't, at least this is what I expected.. Playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogZRgHhgPigXllCAPYCAOwBMBnKAVyIGsiB7AdyKgH4ojKBbAIwgCcoALig969ADYQAhkQDcAKAWhIsAIxZYiFNTpMiaRSugwATJvhJkZYPwCWRAOaGFQA)

Comment: Hmm, this is a completely unrelated followup question and therefore not appropriate for this comment section.  I can tell you that all types extend `unknown` and therefore your link is behaving as intended, but anything more than that really belongs elsewhere (such as a new question post, assuming you can't find one that already addresses it).

Comment: You are right, if you would have a minute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75664221/typescript-conditional-types-but-when-equals-not-when-extends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the time to pull this information out of `ExampleActions` is before you mix it with `Actions` via [interface extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) and before these known keys are absorbed into `string`:

```
interface BaseExampleActions {
    testAction: {}
    testAction2: {}
}

interface ExampleActions extends Actions, BaseExampleActions { }

type Test = keyof BaseExampleActions;
const a: Test = "gfhgfh"; // error!
```

---

But if you already have `ExampleActions` defined that way and really need to extract the known keys and ignore the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), then you can use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to do it:

```
type KnownKeys<T> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as {} extends Record<K, any> ? never : K]: any
}
```

Here what we're doing is checking each key `K` in `keyof T` to see if it's [one of the valid index signature key types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) like `string`, `number`, `symbol` or a *pattern template literal* type such as `` `abc${string}def` ``.  The only way I know of to do that is to test for whether an object with that key type is allowed to be empty.  A [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"a"` fails that test, because `{}` cannot be assigned to `{a: any}`.  But a type like `string` passes, because `{}` *can* be assigned to `{[k: string]: any}`.

Anyway, let's test it out:

```
type Test = KnownKeys<ExampleActions>;
// type Test = "testAction" | "testAction2"
```

Looks good.  `KnownKeys<ExampleActions>` returns just `"testAction" | "testAction2"` and the `string` part is discarded.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhCAzA9gJwgWQEsAPA4AcyQG8AoapepUgFwm3QWQGVSyAbCAILwmBTMCpIAvrQaNgLNhyRCRYqFTqyGAbQDWEAJ4AuJFCbYeAXRPdy-FaOCb6053IXtEqEFAgBRInAYe2FHdRotBhYzBzETSmlI+mimWOAAJnjEhldZZlZPZACgkNVgdQgiFmAAE3U0qAAab19isGDBULUJXKiDGGQAFWgmJABeJH0DTHQW-0D20rCAbjd4NVGQE2GzcaQAIjJ0AAsj4-3lpAB6K6RWbBwAQlpXUEhYJQF0BUIScg0ZAx8oovLY+J0yj1aG5gYVlF1yhokkg9IYTGYLORrEgwUsxG5evRYUo2h0GncqhBavUEeE3LIUml4vSkjcAHQclkuQGRRkIzJI5EMdmc5HZbluJj9ZAAaWAmAA7sAZYYoAAeQYAPj2Uxmgsi2hlckmhj1gyQPiokgp1TqSAAShB1tgamqZc0QMADNqAPxIYAQABurCQJhl2M9BgJPKQUoGSB2owmcsVytVatJePKmtWshuselCZGe32fLK+yQAB8DmXHOl9msNhbtsWJocTmcLtdboGQLwCDVmgAjACuoygx0wI94NSQuAAjiOCLgkGJeAYayM0hXq6Wt-yG5IgA)