# Typescript: conditional types, but when equals not when extends

Tags: typescript

I need to determine Type `TEST<T>` based on if provided one `T` is exactly `unknown`. As certain Typescript Wizard told me already, every type extends from `unknown` so this code below shouldn't work:

```
type TEST<T> = T extends unknown ? number : boolean;

type T1 = TEST<unknown>; //expecting number and it is number
type T2 = TEST<string>; //expecting boolean ant it's not, it's number too
```

How can I achieve expected results? Can I test type equality instead of extendness?

Comment: Does `unknown extends T` work for you?  Are you asking specifically about `unknown`?  Or about a more general type equality detector?  Have you searched for existing questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same) before posting your own new question?

Comment: Yes it works for me, thanks. Yes, even stackoverflow haven't tooltiped me possible duplicate/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@jcalz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75664221/typescript-conditional-types-but-when-equals-not-when-extends#comment133485985_75664221), one solution to your problem could be:

```js
type TEST<T extends unknown> = unknown extends T ? number : boolean;

type T1 = TEST<unknown>;    // number
type T2 = TEST<string>;     // boolean
```

Check it [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogZRgHhlCAPYEB2ATAZygFccBrHAewHccA+KAXhPKtvS10NigH4ocxALYAjCACcoALigjKlADYQAhjgDcAKA2hIsAIxNYiFKQo16aqFAD01gcLHjt4aDABMh+EmQFg4gJY4AOZ0lla2svJKqs66MADMnsbIlCIAVhAAxsChVjZ2cooqOBpAA).